# How can i set dbUrl, other constants as einvironment variable for .net core 2.2 project and how to read those contants inside my .net core 2.2 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables

I have `.net core 2.2` app in which i have to set `dbUrl` and other constants in my project suing environment variables. And i don't have any clue that how can i do that. I have some questions

1) How can i set those variables in as `environment` variables for `.net core` 2.2 project ?
2) How can i get those values stored in `environment variables` at project run time to initialize those constants from `environment variables` in `.net core 2.2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have set dbUrl as environment variable in your system like this

```
"dbUrl":"some_connecting_string"
```

then you can access the same key in your configure services like this

```
string dbUrl= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dbUrl").ToString()
```

**Additional Info**: To know all environment variables of your system.

```
IDictionary environmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in environmentVariables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
        }
```

Comment: i added environment variable on `ec2 linux` instance like this
`export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Prodcution` and getting this variable like this  `IDictionary environmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in environmentVariables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
        }` but not getting environment variable in .net core

Comment: Have you set the end variable in your Linux machine ?

Comment: yes. And i got the reason why i was  not getting environment variables. Because when i set environment variables on `ec2 linux machine` so those variables was set for the `pm2` environment variables because i am using `pm2` for process management. I figure out to set variables in pm2 then i got the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in .NET Core you have one more additional method of accessing environmental variables via `IConfiguration` object - in non-static way as opposed to static `Environment` class. What is good to know is that most probably your system environment variables are already added to this object by default if you configure WebHost using defualt builder.

If they are not however, in Program.cs (or wherever you configure host configuration) add following lines to WebHost builder:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

Or if you are building IConfiguration object explicitly:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

This approach lets you only read environment variables from the system, not set them. Also if you want to dynamically set and get updated value of those variables in the runtime it is not gonna be best approach and you will have to rely on static `Environment` class.

You can read more about it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2